# How to integrate 3D in Flutter

Tags: flutter, 3d, flutter-animation

How can I add 3d in a flutter application? I did some research on it, and I didn't find anything about it.

[React native has a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-gl-model-view) which I haven't checked out, but all I need is to have a 3d object make a spin in the z axis, and the user will be able to change some attributes. Are there any libraries which support that? If not, how can I create it?

Comment: There are plugins for that. Try looking for keywords "3d" and "opengl" on pub.dev.

Comment: [`Transform`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) can give the feeling of 3D, but aren't truly 3D as you can tell when rotating about the X or Y axis by 90 degrees.